# Why in JavaScript +(3,13) returns 13?

Tags: javascript

What's going on here using JavaScript?

```
var c = +(3,13);
```

I got c equals to 13. Why?

Comment: you can check this as well http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-comma-operator

Answer (score 5):

The comma functions as an expression separator operator. The value of a sequence of expressions separated by commas is the value of the last expression. Thus `3, 13` has the value `13`. That's surrounded with parentheses and the unary `+` operator, neither of which will affect that value.

The comma operator is useful in only a small number of situations, generally involving expressions with side effects. In particular, your example is basically pointless. However, there are situations where some statement syntax allows for a single expression, so the comma operator lets you sneak in more than one.